# Change list of code reviewers in TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS 2012 I can go to Team Explorer and click "Request Code Review". On the "New Code Review" section there's a "Enter the name of a reviewer" drop-down. This drop-down seems to have the names of everyone who is an administrator on our TFS server.

My question is, how can we edit this list to include only the people we want doing code reviews?

Comment: Drats! Found the question but not the answer!

Comment: There's another question here on SO with a comment that seems to imply that you can make someone a Reviewer by making them an Administrator but I don't want to do that. Shouldn't there be a Reviewer role somewhere?